# HTTP handlers not registering correctly under Mono MVC 3

Tags: nginx, mono, httphandler, fastcgi

I am at my wit's end.  I'm trying to run an ASP.NET MVC 3 website under Mono via FastCGI and the HTTP handler for Cassette won't register correctly.  The site is http://www.tychaia.com/.

The strange thing is:

- It works fine on my local machine.
- It works fine when the site is run under `xsp4` on the production machine.
- It doesn't work fine when the site is run under `fastcgi-mono-server4` on the production machine.

Things I have tried:

- Checking the Nginx configuration, making sure it's passing in all the correct FastCGI parameters (it is).
- Mono 3.0.7 and 3.0.10.  A friend has it working under 3.0.7, but no dice for me.

It is this particular Web.config entry:

```
<add path="cassette.axd" verb="*" type="Cassette.Aspnet.CassetteHttpHandler, Cassette.Aspnet" />
```

(https://github.com/hach-que/Tychaia/blob/master/Tychaia.Website/Web.config#L47)

As far as I can tell, I have two problems that are causing this issue:

- MVC's IgnoreRoute is not matching the `cassette.axd` URL, even though it is clearly specified at https://github.com/hach-que/Tychaia/blob/master/Tychaia.Website/Global.asax.cs#L20 (and it works under plain old XSP4).  When I add an explicit IgnoreRoute for the string "cassette.axd" (by doing `routes.IgnoreRoute("cassette.axd");`), lo-and-behold, it starts passing through to the handler, except:
- The server's HTTP handler path matching seems to only do exact matches under FastCGI.  Even when I turn off all of the MVC registration in the site, the handler only matches `cassette.axd` and even then it seems like the handler doesn't have any path information.
- When I add further entries like `<add path="cassette.axd/*" verb="*" type="Cassette.Aspnet.CassetteHttpHandler, Cassette.Aspnet" />` these also start being handled by the handler, but it doesn't respond as it normally should at that URL; you just get the default as if there were no additional URL parameters (perhaps they are being consumed by the HTTP handler path matching).

The way that FastCGI is currently setup is:

- Main Nginx instance which is just a reverse proxy into more Nginx instances (I run multiple sites and I like to keep them isolated).  It directs into:
- The Nginx instance for http://tychaia.com/, which calls FastCGI over a UNIX socket.

Again, this issue doesn't occur under XSP4, it's *only* occurring under FastCGI.  While I could reverse proxy this to an XSP4 instance, I'm hesitant to do that for performance reasons.

**Is there anything else I could be missing here?**

**EDIT:** Here's some URLs that should work.  As you can see, they are hitting the StaticFileHandler instead of the Cassette HTTP handler:

- http://tychaia.com/cassette.axd/stylesheet/nDvbK5eAxf6miyaRa_J0vl7YdxA=/Content
- http://tychaia.com/cassette.axd/script/oz4BBh-gK6gJkhB5S64l3mXseFQ=/Scripts

And you can see that with the IgnoreRoute specified explicitly, the `cassette.axd` path does map, but only that path:

- http://tychaia.com/cassette.axd

It doesn't work if you put a slash at the end of it either:

- http://tychaia.com/cassette.axd/

**EDIT 2:** I have updated the site to just link to the `/Content/main.css` file so the site appears correctly while this issue gets sorted; if you check the network requests in your browser, you'll see the failed requests to the Cassette bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have filed a bug on the Mono bug tracker, hopefully to get an answer as to why this is happening:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12190

**UPDATE:** I have found the cause of the issue.  Under OpenSUSE, mono and XSP are packaged seperately.  Even though I upgraded Mono to 3.0.10, XSP/FastCGI still remained at version 2.10.2.0.  When I upgraded the XSP/FastCGI package to 2.11.0.0, the issue disappeared.